# Database size: Neo4j vs SQL servers

Tags: sql-server, neo4j, filesize

I realize the answer will be a bit vague because the schema is not defined here. But I trying to locate data on the database size on Neo4j and SQL servers storing the same set of data. We're trying to project costs of migrating from or mirroring an SQL environment to Neo4j.

Comment: Completely impossible to answer. You can find the relevant sizes for the datatypes for SQL Server in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I would *hope* that Neo4j provides a similar level of information in its documentation. None of that takes into consideration indexes, object definitions, etc, etc.

Comment: It's likely going to be emperic ... what was the experience of a DBA or developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For neo4j, there is a nice knowledge base article on [Understanding Neo4j’s data on disk](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-data-on-disk/).

The article shows you how to estimate the size on disk for a neo4j DB, but you will need to already know your neo4j data model and how many nodes, relationships, properties, etc. your DB will contain.

Comment: That's what I needed. We do know the schema.